# Get element(link) inside iframe google drive

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to programmatically download the two zip files on this page:

https://sites.google.com/site/ucinetsoftware/datasets/covert-networks/siren

The two zip files are actually on separate pages, but the `href` to those pages are inside this page. So, what I want to do:

1. get the links to the pages where each of the two zip files reside (they are on a public google drive)
2. download the two zip files to my computer

(yes, I know I can download them manually, but there are more pages I need to download from, so I would like to automate this process)

Unfortunately, I can't even get the first step going. I start with loading the page into `rvest` and then try to get the element `div.flip-entry-info` but this yields no results. I believe this is because it is part of an `iframe` inside this page. So, how do access the elements that contain the `href` that point to the actual location of these files?

For the second step, I need to find a way to download the data from the google drive.

For example, one of these two zip files is available at: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BFN_1n-5EZ3rLrqrqWsAsBR9exjXuUKF/view.

But I have absolutely no clue as to download the file from there. The 'inspect' option in Chrome doesn't work on this page and `selectorgadget` doesn't reveal anything useful either.

Can anyone help me to download these files through R? I am totally stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the links inside the `iframe`

You can refer tutorial here,

https://github.com/yusuzech/r-web-scraping-cheat-sheet/blob/master/README.md#rvest7.2

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

link = 'https://sites.google.com/site/ucinetsoftware/datasets/covert-networks/siren' %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("iframe") %>%  html_attr("src") 

#get links of both the files
link %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes(".flip-entry-info") %>%  html_nodes('a') %>% 
  html_attr('href')
[1] "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cio3RzjDO6e78PKdEFSPgdw4tCJ7_VUi/view?usp=drive_web"
[2] "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BFN_1n-5EZ3rLrqrqWsAsBR9exjXuUKF/view?usp=drive_web"
```

To download the files we can use `googledrive` library.

```
library(googledrive)
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
drive_download(
  as_id("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cio3RzjDO6e78PKdEFSPgdw4tCJ7_VUi/view?usp=drive_web"), path = temp, overwrite = TRUE)
out<- unzip(temp, exdir = tempdir())
df<- read.csv(out, sep = ",")
str(df)
'data.frame':   44 obs. of  45 variables:
 $ ï..: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ X1 : int  0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ X2 : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X3 : int  1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Comment: Great, that works really well, thanks! Do you also happen to have a solution to the second part of the question: how to download the files from these two `drive.google.com` links? I can't find the actual links of the files on those two pages, and therefore can't figure out how to download them...

Comment: Modified my answer.

Comment: Downloading from the googledrive doesn't work for me. I get the following error:

`Error in `gargle_abort_request_failed()`:
! Client error: (403) Forbidden
Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
* domain: global
* reason: insufficientPermissions
* message: Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes. `

This is weird, since you could download the file just fine (and it is public).

Comment: The error suggests you have not given necessary permissions. Run `drive_auth(email = NA)` to give permissions, refer https://googledrive.tidyverse.org/reference/drive_auth.html

Comment: Thanks. That wasn't it, I had already done this. After a lot of trying I found the solution: I had to run `deauth()ˋ rather than ` drive_auth(email = NA)`. It all works flawlessly now. Thanks a lot for your help, you have helped me greatly!